# JS debounce: how does the timer persist between calls

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at this simple piece of debounce code:

```
function debounce(event, wait) {
    let timer = null;
    return function (...args) {
      clearTimeout(timer); 
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            event.apply(this, args)
        }, wait)
    }
}
```

And suppose we use it in an eventListener

```
window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(handler, 200))
```

Now what I find confusing is that if the `resize` event gets fired multiple times, how does the `timer` inside debounce gets persisted between the calls? The reason I say it gets persisted is that if the same event is triggered within the `delay`, the `timer` is
supposed to be cleared. But since it can be cleared, that means it gets persisted between multiple calls?

Shouldn't it be every time the resize function is fired, we call `debounce` once, and it will give us a new "closure"?

I think I might have some misunderstanding with how eventlistener handle its callback function, so please shine some light on this!

Comment: The event listener is the function _returned_ from `debounce`. So it will have closure around `timer`

Comment: @Nick So is it like: when the eventlistener was first added, debounce was called -> return the function inside. And after this, everytime the event fired, the **same** returned function gets called?

Comment: Correct, the same returned function is called

Comment: Every time a function is called, the variables declared inside are initialized again, in a separate variable environment. It's not that different from an argument. `foo(2); foo(4)` results in two calls of `foo` with two different values for the argument. Similarly, calling `debounce` twice results in two different calls, where each call has its own independent binding for that `timer` local variable inside the closure.

Comment: @CertainPerformance So in this case, I only have one eventlistener that uses debounce, which means debounce gets called once. But its returned function inside the closure gets called everytime the event triggers, so I guess the `timer` variable gets shared everytime since each call of the inside function belong to the same closure? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, the one call of `debounce` results in only one binding for `timer`, that the one returned function references every time it's called